# How to get authentication adapter in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

I am [this](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/165-Login-and-Authentication-with-Zend-Framework.html) tutorial to implement login system in my application. It is giving me following error in process action:

```
Message: Method "getAuthAdapter" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

on following line:

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter($form->getValues());
```

So now I have to implement getAuthAdapter() function but how to code in this function.

Thanks

Comment: as matthew say on top of the tutorial: "For all this to work, you'll need an authentication adapter. I'm not going to go into specifics on this, as the documentation covers them, and your needs will vary based on your site. I will make the assumption, however, that your authentication adapter requires a username and password for authentication credentials. " http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html#zend.auth.introduction.adapters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to authentication via database you can use this code:

```
protected function _getAuthAdapter($userLogin, $userPass){
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
        Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
        'user', //db table name
        'login', // identity column
        'password' // credential column
    );
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($userLogin)->setCredential($userPass);
    return $authAdapter;
}
```

Database authentication docs you can find [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html)

For other adapters look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own authentication function using this [example](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Implementing-Simple-Authentication-Is-This-Secure-td654782.html)

Answer (score 0):

So this is my complete solution:

```
<?php

class AuthenticationController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        // action body
    }

    /**
     * Show login form
     */
    public function loginAction() {

        $this->view->heading = 'Login';
        $this->view->form = new Form_Login();
        $this->view->form->setAction( 'process' );
    }

    /**
     * preDispatch: If user is already logged in then 
     * redirect to index, if not then redirect to login
     */
    public function preDispatch() {

        if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
            // If the user is logged in, we don't want to show the login form;
            // however, the logout action should still be available
            if ('logout' != $this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
                $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
            }
        } else {
            // If they aren't, they can't logout, so that action should 
            // redirect to the login form
            if ('logout' == $this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
                $this->_helper->redirector('login');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Provide authentication adapter
     * 
     * @param unknown_type $values
     */
    public function getAuthAdapter( $values ) {

        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable( Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
                                                      'Authentication',
                                                      'username',
                                                      'password',
                                                      'MD5(CONCAT(salt,?))'
                                                    );

        $authAdapter->setIdentity( $values['username'] );
        $authAdapter->setCredential( $values['password'] );                                         

        return $authAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * Process login request. If user is authenticated
     * then redirect to index otherwise show login form again
     */
    public function processAction() {

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        // Check if we have a POST request
        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            return $this->_helper->redirector('login');
        }

        // Get our form and validate it
        $form = new Form_Login();
        if (!$form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            // Invalid entries
            $this->view->form = $form;
            return $this->render('login'); // re-render the login form
        }

        // Get login form values
        $values = $form->getValues();

        // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
        $adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter( $values );
        $auth    = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $result  = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if (!$result->isValid()) {
            // Invalid credentials
            $form->setDescription('Invalid credentials provided');
            $this->view->form = $form;
            $this->_helper->redirector('login'); // re-render the login form
        }

        // Create session
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
        $session->userEmail = $values['username'];
        $session->userId = '1';

        // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
    }

    /**
     * logout request
     */
    public function logoutAction() {

        // Destroy session
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
        $session->userEmail = null;
        $session->userId = null;

        Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
        $this->_helper->redirector('login'); // back to login page
    }


} // end class


?>
```